# Add custom entity to email template in Shopware 6

Tags: php, entity, shopware

I'm trying to add a new entity to my email templates so I have:
1) I created a new plugin with my custom entity

```
        $connection->executeQuery('
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_entity` (
              `id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
              `message` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
        ');
```

2) I have added the first row in this column:

```
id      | name
bin... | test
```

3) I edit this record in db: `mail_template_type` column `available_entities`
`{"order":"order","salesChannel":"sales_channel","myEntity":"my_entity"}`

And now when I edit the email, twig tells me that there is such a variable to use, but when I use it, there is nothing in it `{{ myEntity.name }}`

Can I have a clear explanation, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you dispatch your own Event to send the mail, you have to implement the `getAvailableData` function and add your Entity to the Collection

```
public static function getAvailableData(): EventDataCollection
{
    return (new EventDataCollection())
        ->add('myEntity', new EntityType(MyEntityDefinition::class));
}
```

Additionally you have to create a getter function to provide the data to the mail template.

```
public function getMyEntity(): MyEntityEntity
{
    return $this->myEntity;
}
```

---

Otherwise if you want to add an entity to an already existing event you can add an association to the entity which is used in the event.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I even added an event to the event_action table and my email is still not being sent. Could you prepare a repository for me with a custom entity and custom event so that I can test it or work?

Comment: I created a small repository for you, hope it will help
[https://github.com/HoelShare/ExampleEventEntity](https://github.com/HoelShare/ExampleEventEntity)

Comment: HoelShare, very thank u for this repository ExampleExtendContactFormEvent. You can only write to me (I will try to do it myself) how can I change all mail templates so that my entity is available in every one?

Comment: If you want to add your entity to every mail template, may be you should decorate the mail service and add your data at this central point. An example can be found here https://gist.github.com/HoelShare/b854064fec8ec23c59a3a1e18675435a